# Laravel & chartjs blank canvas

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts, chart.js

In my project I use Laravel 7.2 with ui bootstrap/vue and want to display a chart from Chart.js.

I don´t want to use any plugins or modules and I prefer like to organize it by myself.

I have tried to implement by this article: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html

Nevertheless it shows an empty canvas element.[image]

This is my app.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-TQq84xX6vkwR0Qs1qH5ADkP+MvH0W+9E7TdHJsoIQiM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @include('layouts.navbar')
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my View

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">User online</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @include('charts.useronline')
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

And this is the partial View

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

What make I wrong? Any Idea? It is possible that I implement the  (i mean the .js files) in wrong order? i have found examples where the scripts above and below were included.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `defer` attribute in the app layout in your laravel html template in "views/layouts/app.blade.php":

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of the reasons behind making script non-deferred. This way the answer will be more helpful for others and well-received.